# Keeping the image "pushed" outside the viewport edge

Tags: css

I am trying to keep an image pushed off right edge (of a viewport) a little bit for mobile devices only, but when I resize the browser the image is "coming back". How do I keep it outside the viewport no matter what and make the "Some text" start beneath the image at it's left border?

https://jsfiddle.net/cv0bmyhL/

```css
body {
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-weight: 800;
}

#topbar {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.center {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

#lower-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 68px;
    font-weight: 500;
    float: right;
    margin: 220px 0px 120px 0;
    
}

#main-pic {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {

    #main-info {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    #topbar {
        display: none;
    }

    #main-pic {
        min-height: 391px;
        min-width: 600px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        position: relative;
        right: -22vw;
    }

    #lower-text {   
        font-size: 21px;
        width: 305px;
        height: 178px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0">
    <div id="topbar">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-3">
           <span style="float: left;">Left</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
           <span class="center">mid</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
           <span class="right">right</span>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="lower-text">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding:0;">
          <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10" id="main-info" style=" margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
            <img id="main-pic" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558521958-0a228e77e984?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
            <span id="page-info">
              Some text
            </span> 
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: to clarify, I'm trying to push the image a little bit off the right edge of the screen (so I don't display the full image, only the part of it) and want to keep the visible part of the pic for all mobile devices, so when I resize the browser I still see the same part of the picture. Also - keep the .col-sm-2 at the left side of the pic blank. I hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself, not only on an external site. CSS is pretty meaningless without something on which to apply. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make a runnable snippet here.

Comment: Are you trying to push the whole image outside the viewport? if so you can do it by changing the property right on the image to -100%

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit? I think you need a mockup of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

So a few things.

You need to remove the `right` CSS from the image itself in order to line up the text and the image.

In order to push the image off the screen, you could do something like I've included, where you let Bootstrap 3 classes that you are using take care of it with their `push` property. You could also add `transform: translateX(____px)` to the `#lower-text` ID to move the image and text off screen.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ff0000 !important;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#topbar {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.center {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

#lower-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 68px;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
}

#main-pic {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
  #main-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  #topbar {
    display: none;
  }
  #main-pic {
    min-height: 391px;
    min-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    position: relative;
  }
  #lower-text {
    font-size: 21px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0">
    <div id="topbar">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span style="float: left;">Left</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <span class="center">mid</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="right">right</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="lower-text">
      <div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding:0;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-push-2" id="main-info" style=" margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
          <img id="main-pic" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558521958-0a228e77e984?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80">
          <span id="page-info">
              Some text
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```